# How to use "Yup" library to calculate the sum of all elements in an array and check with a number?

Tags: javascript, yup

There is an object data

```
{
  products: [{id: 1, sum: 10}, {id: 2, sum: 50}],
  total: 60
}
```

My "yup" circuit looks

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  products: yup.array().of(yup.object().shape({
    id: yup.number().required(),
    sum: yup.number().required(),
  }))
  .min(1)
  .required(),
  total: yup.number().min(10).required(),
});
```

I want to get rid of my functions

```
const checkSum = (data) => {
  let productsTotal = 0;
  const {products, total} = data;
  products.forEach((product) => {
    productsTotal += product.sum;
  });

  if (productsTotal !== total ) return false;

  return true;
}
```

Can you tell me this can be done with "yup"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [**yup test**](https://github.com/jquense/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema)

```js
const schema = object().shape({
  products: array()
    .of(
      object().shape({
        id: number().required(),
        sum: number().required()
      })
    )
    .required()
    .min(1)
    .test(
      'MySumTestName',
      'MySumTestErrorMessage',
      (products, context) =>
        products.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.sum, 0) === context.parent.total
    ),
  total: number().min(10).required()
});
```